# Automating downloading of csv using R

Tags: r, csv, web-scraping, readr

The UK Charity Commission has a site from which you can download charity data for a specified category e.g. dementia
http://beta.charitycommission.gov.uk/charity-search/?q=dementia
[image]

When hovering over the Export Button, the link URL is shown at the bottom with the search item and number of charities included

The actual file downloaded is named
"charitydetails_2017_06_14_23_57_17.csv" so no mention of category/number but with a date-stamp instead

I have tried

```
library(readr)
df <- read_csv("http://beta.charitycommission.gov.uk/charity-search/?q=dementia&exportCSV=317.csv")
```

but just get 404 error

Is there anyways in R that I can automate this so that entering a different term e.g. blind in, say, a shiny app would download the correct dataset into R for processing?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used an incorrect URL. The correct one is:

```
http://beta.charitycommission.gov.uk/charity-search/?q=dementia&exportCSV=1&p=317
```

Comment: Good spot! I kinda got thrown by csv name so did not check URL for error